# How do I wire two lights with a switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

How do you wire two ceiling lights on one switch?  I have installed the switch, and the two lights, but only one light is working.  It is the light that the power source enters.  My setup is like this:

Power  enters first light    + another light   + switch.   The first light is working with the switch (where power enters), but the second is not.  Can you draw a picture for me of the wiring that should be done to make this circuit work?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick ascii art diagram of what you need to have:

```
Power source       First Light   Second Light   Switch
   |  |               |   |         |   |        |  |
   |  |               |   |         |   |        |  |
   |  + white/neutral ----+---------+   |        |  |
   |                  |                 |        |  |
   |                  +-- red/switched -+--------+  |
   |                                                |
   +------- black/hot-------------------------------+
```

Between the second light and the switch, you can run a 2 wire line (just replace the red line with the white and tape the ends of the white with black tape to indicate it's a switched hot). However, between the first and second light, you'll need a 3 wire line to handle the hot/neutral/switched combination.

[image]

Comment: Woudn't you have the neutral wire going to the electrical box with the switch and then tying into the neutral of Light 1 and 2?  Your diagram suggests that you have 1 wire from source to switch and 1 wire from source to light 1, but you'd be running 14/2 or 14/3 cables, not individual wires.

Comment: @Steven Neutral to the switch? From the question, it indicated that the power source was entering the first light fixture. Ideally, it would come into either the second fixture or the switch. I didn't draw this for each x/2 and x/3 wire to each fixture, so I'm sorry for any confusion it creates. One day I'll upgrade to ascii art 2.0.

Comment: LOL v2.0! I can see how Steven is seeing things though. If it helps anybody visualize better, think of the grey rectangle being cut vertically to represent each box, the wires running across each cut representing a single cable. 1st box is supply panel with 14/2 to light box 1. 14/3 between light box 1 and 2. 14/2 between light box 2 and switch box, except it would be marked white and black instead of red and black.

Comment: I have to do a similar thing: run two lights where there was just one on a switch before. (Is this OK to do?) I added a graphic to make sure I was interpreting the ASCII art correctly. So given the existing set-up (let's say Light 1 connected to the switch), I will just need to jumper both wires coming from Light 2 to the lines that go out to Light 1? Still a bit confused, but this answer is helpful.

Comment: @beroe If light 1 is connected to both the switch and the power source, and you're adding light 2, then your problem is much simpler. Just add a 2 wire line from light 1 to light 2, and add that line in to where the wire nuts are connecting the light fixture at light 1. If you're still confused, post a separate question since it's different than this one.

Comment: @BMitch I finally got around to trying this and it worked just fine to follow your instructions. Thanks.