# Connect 1 power source to 2 sets of 2-light switch

Tags: switch, power

Based on the diagram in this thread

Link:
[How do I wire two lights with a switch?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/23294/how-do-i-wire-two-lights-with-a-switch)
or ascii:

```
    Power source       First Light   Second Light   Switch
   |  |               |   |         |   |        |  |
   |  |               |   |         |   |        |  |
   |  + white/neutral ----+---------+   |        |  |
   |                  |                 |        |  |
   |                  +-- red/switched -+--------+  |
   |                                                |
   +------- black/hot-------------------------------+
```

How should I wire to a 1 power source if I have 2 sets of a 2-light switch setup? Should I just simply tap on the power source? What if I have 6 sets to 1 power source?

Comment: Using ASCII art for wiring diagrams, should be illegal.

Comment: Tester101, I didn't know asciis are frowned upon. I copied it from the original thread I referred to and thought it would help to understand. Now I know.

Comment: It's just my personal opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ascii, nice.  There's many ways to wire it depending but this is the most straightforward way to illustrate it:

```
Source ---blk--- Switch ---blk--- Light1 ---blk--- Light2 ---blk--- Light3 etc.
       ---wht---        ---wht---        ---wht---        ---wht---
```

The idea is that although the lights are electrically in parallel, the wiring "daisy chains" from one to the next.  The switch can tie into the chain at either end or in the middle, it doesn't matter.

Now with two switches, it gets a little more interesting - you want different kind of switches, and three wires plus ground between the switches.  (No more asccii, going to reuse someone elses drawing...)

[image: three way switch wiring illustration]

Comment: I wonder how we'd answer 3-way switch questions without BuildMyOwnCabin.com...  I have used those several times!

Comment: Thank you, batsplatsterson! This helps a lot to see how to "daisy chain" from one power source. Originally, I was thinking more of 1 switch for each pair of lights for a total of 6 sets (1 switch/2lights) independent of each other but "chained" to 1 power source.